# Adding Key to BuildConfig and calling it inside @header kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So I don't want to share the api key by accident, but unlike Java I don't know how to call the API_KEY in my buildconfig file inside the Header.

Sample Code:

interface Api {

```
// This is how it looks but it exposes my API
    @Headers(
        "x-rapidapi-key: hwyehajkse.qjkdagf,kjbgekuh,jc", //currentfakeAPI
        "Content-type:application/json"
    )

I have managed to add the API in BuildConfig files but how can I call it on the header the below method is what I tried but it wont work.
    @Headers(
            "x-rapidapi-key:",API_KEY,
           "Content-type:application/json"
   )
```

Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this cool feature in Kotlin.

```
@Headers(
   "x-rapidapi-key:$API_KEY",
   "Content-type:application/json"
)
```

prefix

> $

to the variable you want to use along with the string

> ${`method.variable`}

to access a variable from a method.

Eg:

```
@Headers(
       "x-rapidapi-key:${BuildConfig.API_KEY}",
       "Content-type:application/json"
    )
```